Angular - show image in html over promise
In my Angular application I use this code:
    <table style="margin-left:20px;">
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td>
                <img style="height:45px;width:45px;" [src]="getProfileImage(user)" />
            </td>
            <td>{{user.surname}} {{user.firstname}} {{user.title}}</td>
            <td>
                <ion-icon name="remove-outline" (click)="removeUser(user)" title="l&ouml;schen"></ion-icon>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

The getProfileImage methode looks like this:
getProfileImage(user: User) {
  var self = this;
  this.profileService.getProfileImage(user.profileImagePath!, user.id!, function(dataUrl) {
      user.profileImage = dataUrl;
    });
}

How can I make it that the profileImage is shown in HTML.
Currently nothing is shown - the images are empty.

The method getProfileImage calls profileService.getProfileImage which sets user.profileImage but getProfileImage returns nothing. You better call getProfileImage for each user in controller and bind image source to user.profileImage.
